# Java resource bundle is loaded from another module

Tags: java, properties, resources

Currently my project contains 3 modules, 1 named generic (which is based for other 2) ,
first named Romania and second named Cyprus, inside of them i have a little code (which does not contain the logic of calling bundles). In the all 3 modules i have resources -> language and here i have first_en_US_CUSTOM (Cyprus module) , first_en_US_CUSTOM (generic module) and same in the Romania. The logic to load this is:

```
private String getTranslated(ResourceBundle resourceBundle) { // resource bundle comes with locale en_US
        String result = null;
        

                try {
                    String text = resourceBundle.getString(key);
                    result = text;
                } catch (MissingResourceException var7) {
                    System.out.println("No resource found");
                    }
                
        return result;
    }
```

While calling this (it is called from a JAR file) , it returns the string from Cyprus module, however Romanian module is running (obv. it should take it from Romanian module). if i remove the first_en_US from Cyprus module then i get it in Romanian moudule and generic one, however -> it takes from generic module now. What is the problem here? Where should i search? I am debugging and can't find at all the problem or where it loads from.

Answer (score 0):

First (if you should not know it already): since java 9 *.properties can be edited in UTF-8, without `\uXXXX` which for Greek is great. The problem here is class path/locale related.

The Locale adds a suffix to the file. It could also be a problem using the same path to the properties but different contents. A problem when falling back on the generic root locale. (Maybe java's module system might help.)

```
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("foo.bar.Baz", locale);
```